# How to determine number of objects in array

Tags: c#, arrays

Once again I cannot find a solution myself (I have tried using Array.IndexOf(db, accnum) with a pos > -1 return boolean, but have reverted to this loop after I couldn't make it work).
So, I thought using db.Length would leave 'a' at the length of all the non-null elements in the array, however it seems to count the whole array, meaning that when the loop reaches a null element it causes an error. Is there a way to halt the loop count when it runs out of objects in the array?

```
void withdrawal()
{
    int accnum;
    double withdrawal;

    //get and parse input details
    accnum = int.Parse(tbNameEnt.Text);
    withdrawal = double.Parse(tbBalaEnt.Text);

    //check if account exists within existing objects
    int a = db.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (db[i].GetAccNo() == accnum)
        {
            pos = i;

            //deduct from balance
            db[pos].SetBalance(db[pos].GetBalance() - withdrawal);

            WithMess(); //success message
            hide_form();
            MakeWith2.Visible = false;
            show_menu();
            break;
        }

        else if ((db[i].GetAccNo() != accnum) && (i == db.Length - 1))
        {
            //account doesn't exist message
            MessageBox.Show("Account does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why use an array at all?  Why not use a collection, in which case there would be no "empty" items?  You can just add and remove and the collection will grow and shrink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are null items that pad the array.. break out of the loop when you reach one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
   if (db[i] == null)
        break;
   // the rest
```

Alternatively, use LINQ to filter the null items out:

```
foreach (var item in db.Where(x => x != null)) {
    // loop here
}
```